# Combobox Dependency

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

I have a problem with dependent comboboxes. I want to have two comboboxes, the second one will be dependent dependent on the first, so if I choose a value on the first I want the second one to only show the options that are related to that first value.

For that purpose I'm working with a dictionary but I can't manage to do what I want. I am quite new with tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry('800x600')
window.configure(bg = 'Dodgerblue4')

dict = {'A': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'B': ['4', '5', '6'],
        'C': ['7', '8', '9']}

tk.Label(text = "HWCI: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
varhwci = tk.StringVar()
valor_hwci = ttk.Combobox(window, values = list(dict.keys()), state="readonly", textvariable = varhwci)
valor_hwci.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event: varhw.set(dict[varhwci.get()]))
valor_hwci.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

tk.Label(text = "HW: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
varhw = tk.StringVar()
lista = varhw.get()
valor_hw = ttk.Combobox(window, state="readonly", values = varhw.get())
valor_hw.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use a `StringVar` for your `Combobox`. Just create a function to modify your 2nd `Combobox` directly upon selection:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry('800x600')
window.configure(bg = 'Dodgerblue4')

d = {'A': ['1', '2', '3'],
        'B': ['4', '5', '6'],
        'C': ['7', '8', '9']}

tk.Label(text = "HWCI: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)

def func(event=None):
    valor_hw["values"] = d.get(valor_hwci.get())
    valor_hw.current(0)

valor_hwci = ttk.Combobox(window, values = list(d.keys()), state="readonly")
valor_hwci.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', func)
valor_hwci.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

tk.Label(text = "HW: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
valor_hw = ttk.Combobox(window, state="readonly")
valor_hw.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

Also on a side note, don't name your dictionary as dict as it shadows the built-in method `dict`.

Comment: Just for curiosity, could it be done using StrinVar?

Comment: Probably, but I usually don't see the need to use a StringVar for combobox.